# Proving Peano's Theorem via Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I am currently doing this problem.

(a) Define what it means for a sequence of functions $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be equicontinuous on $[0,1]$. State the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem.

(b) Given a continuous function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can inductively define functions $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $n \geqslant 0$ by $f_{n+1}(t)=\int_0^t \varphi\left(f_n(s)\right) \mathrm{d} s$, and $f_0(t)=0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $T_1>0$ so that the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n \geqslant 1}$ is equi-bounded and equi-continuous on $\left[0, T_1\right]$.

(c) Deduce the existence of $T_2 \in\left(0, T_1\right]$ and a continuously differentiable function $f:\left[0, T_2\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f^{\prime}(t)=\varphi(f(t))$ on $\left[0, T_2\right]$. [Hint: Prove that if $T_2 \in\left(0, T_1\right]$ is small enough, $R_n(t)=f_{n+1}(t)-f_n(t) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\left.\left[0, T_2\right].\right]$

Part (b) was fine.

For part (c), it is clear that applying Arzela-Ascoli to the $f_n$ gives a convergent subsequence. Moreover, with the hint in hand it would be clear that the limit of the subsequence is a solution to the ODE.

It is not clear however how the hint in part (c) could be proved without assuming that $\varphi$ is Lipschitz.

None of the proofs I can find online use the shrinking argument of $T_1$ to $T_2$.